# Git auto-merging removed some information while cherry-picking

Tags: c#, git, cherry-pick

At work, I had to include a commit from a remote branch to my local branch.

Because I did not want to merge yet, I cherry-picked the remote commit to my local branch.

While cherry-picking, Git performed an auto-merge whithout prompting me for a conflict.

I then realized that some vital lines of code from the remote were missing from the resulting commit.

I put the case here:

https://github.com/apicoding/SimplePrj

**1.**  My 'Initial commit' in master is missing the mandatory 'Print()' method implementation.

**2.** The 'Print()' method is defined in 'Ready to merge' commit in remote.

**3.**  After cherry-picking/auto-merge 'Ready to merge' commit to master,
    the 'Print()' method is still undefined.

**Do you have an explanation why git cherry-pick can choose to remove some information whitout raising a conflict and asking the user to choose ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're cherrypicking, you're taking the commit you cherrypick into your branch, so if you cherrypicked the `Ready to merge` commit from `remote` then only the comment `//ready to merge` went to your branch (which is the only change that commit has).

If you wanted to take all the changes from `remote` you should've merged the branch, not cherrypicked that single commit.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfectly explained, thank you so I will cherry-pick the remote commit chain to get what I want.